# jQuery slider - set min and max as same as two handles' values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Maybe I'm just not getting something simple here, but I am not able to set the min and max values as the same as the handle values in my jQuery slider. The min and max are dynamically defined via php variables, and when the slider first appears, I want it's range to be the same as the range between the min and the max, i.e. the entire slider. If the user wants to then make changes, they can do so -- it is for an ajax search filter.

When I try the below code, the range sliders get stuck all the way to the left and cannot be moved.

Here is my js:

```
var pay_max = $('#pay_max').html();
var pay_min = $('#pay_min').html();

$(function() {
$( "#pay_range" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: pay_min,
    max: pay_max,
    values: [ pay_min, pay_max ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#filter_by_pay" ).html( "Pay Range: ¥" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - ¥" + ui.values[ 1 ] ).css("color", "black");
    }
});
```

my html:

```
 <div class = "hidden" id="pay_max"><?=max($all_teachers['pay']);?></div>
 <div class = "hidden" id="pay_min"><?=min($all_teachers['pay']);?></div>

        <div class = "filter_options" id="pay_filter">
            <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
            <div id ="pay_range"></div>
        </div>
```

It works okay if I, for instance, change the min to 0, but that is not the goal. I only want the range slider to be within the bounds of the initial values, which also happen to be the min and max.

Comment: Can we see the html where `pay_max` and `pay_min` are defined?

Comment: just added it to my post -- oh woops, one sec

Comment: oh, I want to see `pay_max` and `pay_min` not `pay _range` though I'd have asked for that next. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use string values where you need numbers:

Try:

```
var pay_max = 1*$.trim($('#pay_max').html());
var pay_min = 1*$.trim($('#pay_min').html());
```

used `$.trim` to be sure don't have any whitespace

Comment: works beautifully, thanks, will checkmark it when it becomes available. any other way to make it a number besides multiplying by 1? or is that the best way

Comment: lots of ways... google `javascript string to number`